# Observable.zip is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, typescript2.1

> VM95422:27 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_rxjs_Observable**.Observable.zip is not a function

Tried various imports

```
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/zip';
// import 'rxjs/add/observable/zip-static';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/zip';
import 'rxjs/operator/zip';
```

Trying to use it like that:

```
const zippedUsers: Observable<User[]> = Observable.zip<User>(this.usersObservable);
```

Angular 4, TypeScript 2.1.6

package.json:

```
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
```

Comment: `import "rxjs/add/observable/zip";`

Comment: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html

Comment: Could you consider changing the accepted answer since it's no longer correct for the recent RxJS versions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

maybe something like

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/zip";
```

then something like:

```
Observable.zip(this.someProvider.getA(), this.someProvider.getB())
        .subscribe(([a, b]) => {
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
        });
```

Answer (score 9):

### RxJS 6

Starting from RxJS 6...

### [`Observable` creation functions](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#observable-creation-functions)

such as `from()`, `fromPromise()`, `of()`, `zip()` should be imported like this:

```
import { from, fromPromise, of, zip } from 'rxjs';
```

and used as a plain function call:

```
const data: Observable<any> = fromPromise(fetch('/api/endpoint'));
```

### [Pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

should be imported like this:

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and used as `pipe()` method arguments:

```
const someObservable: Observable<number> = ...;
const squareOddVals = someObservable.pipe(
        filter((n: number) => n % 2 !== 0),
        map(n => n * n))
    .subscribe((n: number): void => ...);
```

Comment: The question explicitly mentions rxjs 5, so this doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @IngoBürk: I believe RxJS 5 was just the version OP was using at the time of asking (more than 2yrs ago). Nowadays, I think it's more beneficial for the community if this question is kept in-sync with the current versions of libs especially taking into account this is the top question in Google search for the matter.

Comment: @IngoBürk: Also, notive [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882587/3345644) answer which provides information related to RxJS 5.5 which also is a higher version than OP asked. But nobody has been complaining half a year already :)

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov thanks a lot: import from accepted answer stopped working after update 6->7, import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; works

Answer (score 8):

5.5 rxjs:

```
import {zip} from "rxjs/observable/zip";
const zippedUsers: Observable<User[]> = zip(this.usersObservable);
```

Comment: I spent more than 90 minutes trying to find this solution. None of the material or documentation I found by google helped. But your answer did.