# Property 'zip' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using angular 6 as well as read about pipe but didn't get any proper syntax to write zip and imported zip as well.
**Error**: Property 'zip' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

```
import { zip } from 'rxjs/operators';

callZipFunction(): void {
            Observable
            .zip( this.commonService.GetMethodA(), this.commonService.GetMethodB())
            .subscribe(([a,b])=>{
            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);
            });
        }
```

Comment: What version of rxjs are you trying to use?

Comment: "rxjs": "~6.3.3"

Comment: then try `import { zip } from 'rxjs';` and remove the `Observable` and the dot in front of `.zip` ...

Comment: You're welcome.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to import this way

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/zip";
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46335331/8612835)

Answer (score 2):

@dmcgrandle Thanks for resolving the Issue

```
import { zip  } from 'rxjs';

    callZipFunction(): void {
        zip( this.commonService.GetMethodA(), this.commonService.GetMethodB())
        .subscribe(([a,b])=>{
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have code this like;

```
  let source$ = Observable.range(0, this.value).zip(
   Observable.timer(0, 1000),
   (x) => { return x }
  ).map(x => {
   return this.value - x
  });
```

Add;

```
    import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
    import "rxjs/add/operator/zip";
```